# Custom cell in UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, swift, custom-cell

If I put in a prototype cell in UITableViewController UILabel, UIImageView, etc. and do the outlet, then I get the error: **Connection cannot have a prototype object as its destination**.

I decided to do differently: I put in a cell prototype I needed elements assigned to each a tag. Now I try to display information using tags. In Objective-C, it looks something like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LocationCell"];

Location *location = [_locations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = location.title;
UILabel *date = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
date.text = location.place;
```

I can not understand how I do it on Swift. Help please. I tried like this, but did not work:

```
    var postImage:UIImageView = UIImageView()
    postImage.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL.URLWithString(wordpressArray[indexPath!.row].url)))
    cell!.viewWithTag(103)
    var postTitle:UILabel = UILabel()
    postTitle.text = wordpressArray[indexPath!.row].post_title
    cell!.viewWithTag(101)
```

Comment: Please show the attempts you have already made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've tried to attach your `UILabel` and `UIImageView` on the `UITableViewCells` default property.

Declare your own custom Subclass from `UITableViewCell`, and name your own properties (preferably not like the super class)